# Return records in an unusual offset order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Currently I have a scope that pulls back my records in the following standard order:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

and it is converted in to a html block that's laid out as so:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I want a html block that's laid out like so:

```
1 6 11 16
2 7 12 
3 8 13
4 9 14
5 10 15
```

So I think I need to pull the records back in the following order - (records offset by the number of rows)

```
1 6 11 16 2 7 12 3 8 13 4 9 14 5 10 15
```

Any idea what is the neatest way to do this in Rails / ActiveRecord?

Comment: Customer ordering straight from the db is possible but extremely clunky and I wouldn't recommend it. I would implement the ordering in the view if possible, or the controller. I'm not too up on front-end, but I bet there is some css / javascript package you can use to display items in columns with very little effort. Failing that, you can write the ordering in the controller using any Ruby logic you can imagine, e.g., using the `transpose` method on Array. This will be infinitely more readable and maintainable than trying to pull the records from the db in a specific custom order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know how many columns you want to eventually render. I think this must work for you:

```
columns = 5
MyModel.order(:id).in_groups_of(columns).transpose
```

And you get an array of lines, each one with an array of records.

If you want an unique array you can add `.flatten` at the end.

Comment: Great stuff. This was the way to go. You actually need to know the columns not rows: `.in_groups(columns).transpose.flatten.reject(&:blank?)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't do that with AR ordering! You will have to do that in your controller or the view.

Comment: huh, any example you'd like to share?

Comment: Here is to get you started: `num = 5; array.each_slice(num).with_index { |(*cols), i| columns[i] = cols }; columns.length.times { |i| ... }`.